# Getting "invalid credentials" When Performing Fusion Tables INSERT From A Google Gadget

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-fusion-tables

We have a Google Gadget that connects to Fusion Tables through the Fusion Table API with the user’s Google Account.  It performs SELECT and INSERT.

We built the gadget using OAuth1 (shindig library for opensocial).  It worked fine for the deprecated version of the Fusion Table API.  When we migrated it to the new PAPI, the select qworks fine because authentication with OAuth2 is not necessary.  For the INSERT however, it is necessary.  The documentation for opensocial has not been completely updated:http://docs.opensocial.org/display/OSREF/OpenSocial+Specification+Considerations

I cannot figure out how to successfully use OAuth2 to perform an Insert.  We have the API privileges to read/write at the domain level and the user has owner privileges to the Fusion table.

The error I am getting is saying “Invalid Credentials”  Pretty vague and I cannot tell why.

Here is our gadget header:

```
<OAuth>
    <Service name="google">
    <Access url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken" method="GET" />
    <Request url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables%20https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private"
         method="GET" />
    <Authorization url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_callback=http://oauth.gmodules.com/gadgets/oauthcallback" />
    </Service>
</OAuth>
```

I am not sure exactly how to update, so I added another header:

```
<OAuth2>
    <Service name="google">
    <Authorization url="https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_callback=http://oauth.gmodules.com/gadgets/oauth2callback" />
    </Service>
</OAuth2>
```

When we make the call, we do the following:

```
options = {};
options[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.CONTENT_TYPE] = gadgets.io.ContentType.TEXT;
options[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.METHOD] = gadgets.io.MethodType.POST;
options[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.POST_DATA] = postData;
options[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.AUTHORIZATION] = gadgets.io.AuthorizationType.OAUTH2;
options[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.HEADERS] = {'Authorization':'{encrypted fusiontable key}'};  //not sure if this helps but its extra
options[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.OAUTH_SERVICE_NAME] = "google";
options[gadgets.io.RequestParameters.OAUTH_USE_TOKEN] = "always";

URL = https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?key={encrypted fusiontable key} &client_id={id number}”;
postData=”sql=INSERT…”;
gadgets.io.makeRequest(URL, handlerWrapper, options);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a write request, you will need to supply the oauth token that encodes the user's permission to access the table.  It looks like this might be in gadgets.io.RequestParameters.OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN.  The key is used for read access from public tables.  Also, you may need to set the OAUTH_SERVICE_NAME to "fusiontables".

Comment: Warren, thank you.  Would you have any sample code that provides an example of this?